# Delay Loading of Homepage Until All Templates are Loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm running into an issue in which my homepage loads faster than the other templates in AngularJS. What would be the best way to delay loading of the homepage until ALL of the templates are loaded? Essentially the issue I am running into is that after the homepage loads, the user clicks a different route in the navigation bar and it doesn't go to that route. Then after some more clicking (like a 5 second delay), it goes to the desired route (and all the other ones work as well after that).

Here is the `$routeProvider` method call:

**ANGULAR**

```
App.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: home,
            controller: 'mainController',
            resolve: mainCont.resolve
        })
        .when('/gym', {
            templateUrl: gym,
            controller: 'gymController',
            resolve: gymCont.resolve
        })
        .when('/instructors', {
            templateUrl: instructors,
            controller: 'instructorsController',
            resolve: instructorCont.resolve
        })
        .when('/classes', {
            templateUrl: classes,
            controller: 'classesController',
            resolve: classCont.resolve
        })
        .when('/media', {
            templateUrl: media,
            controller: 'mediaController',
            resolve: mediaCont.resolve
        })
        .when('/shop', {
            templateUrl: shop,
            controller: 'shopController'
        })
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: contact,
            controller: 'contactController',
            resolve: contactCont.resolve
        })
        .when('/admin', {
            templateUrl: admin,
            controller: 'adminController'
        });
 });
```

I have tried to put an element that covers the whole screen until the window is fully loaded, but it doesn't work for all of the templates:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
        $("#cover").hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try using a `$routeChangeSuccess` event for setting a scope variable for your loading symbol or hiding purpose

```
app.run(['$rootScope', function($root) {
  $root.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(e, curr, prev) { 
    if (curr.$$route && curr.$$route.resolve) {
      // Show a loading message until promises aren't resolved
      $root.loadingView = true;
    }
  });
  $root.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(e, curr, prev) { 
    // Hide loading message
    $root.loadingView = false;
  });
}]);
```

you can do it for one view or all views in general. and use `ng-show="loadingView"` to show hide your navigation panel.